# Angular AuthGuard with roles from firebase cant be used

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs

I tried to create a Guard which should check if the user has an admin role or not.
For this purpose, I have in my Cloud Firestore a boolean (admin = true | false).

When I try to check, if the current user is an admin or not, I get the following error message:

**Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/map'**

My admin-guard.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AdminAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

    return this.auth.user$.pipe(
      take(1),
      map(user => user && user.admin ? true : false),
      tap(isAdmin => {
        if (!isAdmin) {
          console.error('Access denied - Admins only');
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

My auth.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  user$: Observable<AppUser>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private afs: AngularFirestore) {

    this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(switchMap(user => {
      if (user) {
        return this.afs.doc<AppUser>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
      } else {
        return of(null);
      }
    }));
  }
}
```

My user-interface:

```
export interface AppUser {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
  admin?: boolean;
}
```

Would be great if anyone could give me a hint on how to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: did you try import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the problem by removing the import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
and use instead import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';